# What is DataType<T>::work_type for?

Tags: c++, opencv, types

OpenCV offers the `DataType` class to obtain a mapping from (some) fundamental c++ types to OpenCV types. In some situation I use it in `Mat` initialisation, sometimes in `assert`s, mainly to ensure that I don't use wrong (fundamental) types in `Mat::at()`.

Documentation on the class is scarce, so:

What should I use the member type `work_type` for? What's its meaning?
When you have an answer for me, do you also have a pointer to some piece of documentation, please? :)

The documentation I can find in the `4.5.1` source code informs on `DataType` being deprecated in favour of `traits`. The latter doesn't seem to provide the `work_type` anymore. Is this an indication that the member type is of no use?

As some people seem to browse through question to demand a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) reflexively, here you are:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

template< typename T >
void outTypeInfo( std::string const &name ) {
    std::cout << std::setw(20) << name
              << " - DataType - depth: " << cv::DataType<T>::depth << " " << std::setw(10) << cv::typeToString(cv::DataType<T>::depth)
              << " - type: " << cv::DataType<T>::type << " " << std::setw(10) << cv::typeToString(cv::DataType<T>::type)
              << " - gen. type: " << cv::DataType<T>::generic_type << " " << std::setw(10) << cv::typeToString(cv::DataType<T>::generic_type)
              << " -      fmt: " << cv::DataType<T>::fmt //<< " " << std::setw(10) << cv::typeToString(cv::DataType<T>::fmt)
              << " - work type: " << typeid(typename cv::DataType<T>::work_type).name()
              << "\n                    "
              << " - traits   - depth: " << cv::traits::Depth<T>::value << " " << std::setw(10) << cv::typeToString(cv::traits::Depth<T>::value)
              << " - type: " << cv::traits::Type<T>::value << " " << std::setw(10) << cv::typeToString(cv::traits::Type<T>::value)
              << " - safe type: " << cv::traits::SafeType<T>::value << " " << std::setw(10) << cv::typeToString(cv::traits::SafeType<T>::value)
              << " - safe fmt: " << cv::traits::SafeFmt<T>::fmt //<< " " << std::setw(10) << cv::typeToString(cv::traits::SafeFmt<T>::fmt)
              << "\n";
}

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main( [[maybe_unused]]int argc, [[maybe_unused]]char *argv[] ) {
    outTypeInfo<unsigned char>( "unsigned char" );
}
```

Comment: Well, looking at https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/traits.hpp it seems to remap boolean along with 8 and 16 bit signed and unsigned integers to `int`, and `float16_t` to `float`, and also applying that of any composites of those primitives (`Vec`, `Size`, `Point`, etc.). Long time ago (older 3.x and 2.4.x releases) it was used to format elements (like when printing to stdout), but that appears to have been replaced by more sophisticated formatting. Other than that, it's hard to find many other uses, even going 9 years back...

Comment: Don't really have any documentation source, and haven't ran across any. I just dug through my archive of OpenCV releases.

Comment: Thanks for your historical research on the question, @DanMašek . The best bet then seems to be that the type is of not much use.